# How can I change the size of the strip on facets in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to control the size of the strips on facets in a ggplot? I tried using `strip.background=element_rect(size=n)` but as far as I can tell it didn't actually do anything. Is this even possible?

Comment: A somewhat unpleasant hack would be to include newlines (`\n`) in the strip text to increase their size.

Comment: In `element_rect`, size refers to the point size of the bounding line, it won't really help you make the rectangle bigger or smaller.

Comment: would converting the plot to a `ggplotGrob` `TableGrob` then looking for `strip_` grobs and modifying the `height`element work? I don't have time to test that now, but I know others fiddle at the grob layer, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

converting the plot to a gtable manually lets you tweak the strip height,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear)) + 
            geom_bar(aes(y=gear), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
            facet_wrap(~cyl)

g <- ggplotGrob(d)
g$heights[[3]] = unit(1,"in")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this - I saw some mentions of ggplotGrob in similar questions, but none that showed this particular change, and I wasn't sure how to approach it. I'll give it a try later today and play around with it.

Comment: Well, it works, but I don't know why. Is there a decent tutorial that can teach me more about how to use these gtables? I can't figure them out...

Comment: unfortunately there isn't a tutorial, and gtable developers have moved on to new projects. The best reference is probably here, browsing the [gtable tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtable). I started writing [some doc](https://github.com/baptiste/gtable/wiki/Description), but quite frankly I lost motivation seeing that the developers wouldn't accept pull requests.

Comment: library(grid) is needed to run grid.newpage()