# How to decrease padding around facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, themes, facet

How can I reduce the size of the title margin or padding (the grey regions circled in the graph below). I can shrink the title text size, but the title box size/padding is too large in plots with many facets.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scale="free_x") +
  geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=5))
```

[image]

Comment: Try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407355/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-the-strip-on-facets-in-a-ggplot

Comment: Great thanks- I couldn't find it with my keyword search